# Is it common to have only one ViewModel to manage all CoreData entities - Core Data + MVVM + SwiftUI

Tags: swift, mvvm, core-data, swiftui

Is it common to have only one `ViewModel` to manage all `CoreData` entities?

For instance, in the following example, I have three Core Data entities, `Car`, `CarService` and `ServiceRecord` where `Car` has many `carServices` and each `CarService` has many `serviceRecords`. Everything is working fine but I feel like my `CarViewModel` file is growing and growing and I'm not sure if this is really a good MVVM practice.

As you can see in the following example I'm using `CarViewModel` to fetch data from `Core Data` and passing it around SwiftUI views. Again, everything is working fine but I feel like I'm missing something.

Can someone please share how you usually structure your code when using `MVVM + CoreData + SwiftUI`. Do you handle everything from one `ViewModel` as shown below or do you usually have a `ViewModel` for each entity? If a viewModel per each entity is the best option, what method do you use to pass viewModels around SwiftUI views?

### CoreDataManager

```
class CoreDataManager{

    static let instance = CoreDataManager()

    lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return container.viewContext
    }()
    
    lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
        return setupContainer()
    }()
    
    func setupContainer()->NSPersistentContainer{
        // code to setup container...
        return container
    }
    
    func save(){
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch let error{
            print("Error saving Core Data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

### CarViewModel

```
class CarViewModel: ObservableObject{

    let manager: CoreDataManager
    
    @Published var cars: [Car] = []
    @Published var carServices: [CarService] = []
    @Published var serviceRecords: [ServiceRecord] = []
    
    init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = .instance){
        self.manager = coreDataManager
        // getCars() etc.
    }

    // CREATIONS
    func addCar(name:String){}
    func addService(name:String, cost: Double){}
    func createRecord(name:String, cost: Double){}
    
    // DELETES
    func deleteCar(){}
    func deleteCarService(){}
    func deleteServiceRecord(){}
    
    // UPDATES
    func updateCar(){}
    func updateService(){}

    // GETS
    func getCars(){}
    func getServices(){}
    func getRecords(){}
    
    func save(){
        self.manager.save()
    }
}
```

## SwiftUI Views

### CarsView

```
struct CarsView: View {
    @StateObject var carViewModel = CarViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                List {
                    ForEach(carViewModel.cars) { car in
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

### ServicesView

```
struct ServicesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var carViewModel:CarViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                List {
                    ForEach(carViewModel.carServices) { service in
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

### RecordsView

```
struct RecordsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var carViewModel: CarViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                List {
                    ForEach(carViewModel.serviceRecords) { record in
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer to have one view model per view

Comment: @JoakimDanielson For some reason, this sounds like a cleaner way to maintain code. With this approach, I would assume you would have a `CarViewModel`, a `CarServiceViewModel` and a `ServiceRecordsViewModel` that would only handle single-entity-related data coming from Core Data, correct?  With this approach, have you ever run into the need to share data between two different ViewModels? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes you might need to deal with multiple model (entity) types in one model but most of the time for me at least only the main one is mutable while the other are immutable in the context of a specific view model. Like when working with a Service then you assign/select a Car for the Service object being created or edited

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - One last question, when using Core Data, do you manage the view's logic and the Core Data fetch requests within the same ViewModel? For instance, in the `ServicesViewModel` would you handle the logic for the `ServicesView` at self and any fetch request from CoreData for this particular view?

Comment: view model objects aren't used in SwiftUI at all, you have to fully learn the View struct, DynamicProperty structs and property wrappers inc. `@Environment` for the context and `@FetchRequest`

Comment: Yes I would do that.

Comment: @malhal you are everywhere with your claim that view models aren’t used with SwiftUI but this is your opinion and not a fact, on the contrary they are quite commonly used. And for instance `@FetchRequest` is far from a solution that fits all needs, I have a few in my current project but far more places where I use a NSFetchRequest in a view model or service class

Comment: Yes it's a common mistake. If @FetchRequest doesn't fit your needs then you could build your own DynamicProperty struct that does the same thing but resorting to a legacy view model object is not the correct approach you have to learn the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create a service file which holds all the functions to a given model. I would then only expose the functions in my viewModel that my viewController needs.

For example:

**CarService.swift**

```
class CarService {
    func addCar(name:String) {}
    func addService(name:String, cost: Double) {}
    func createRecord(name:String, cost: Double) {}

    // DELETES
    func deleteCar() {}
    func deleteCarService() {}
    func deleteServiceRecord() {}

    // UPDATES
    func updateCar() {}
    func updateService() {}

    // GETS
    func getCars() {}
    func getServices() {}
    func getRecords() {}
}
```

**CarViewModel.swift**

```
protocol CarViewModelType {

    func addCar(name: String)
    func deleteCar()

}

class CarViewModel: CarViewModelType {

    var carService: CarService

    init(service: CarService) {
        self.carService = service
    }

    func addCar(name: String) {
        self.carService.addCar(name: name)
    }

    func deleteCar() {
        self.carService.deleteCar()
    }
}
```

**CarViewController.swift**

```
class CarViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel: CarViewModelType!

}
```

This is of course just one way to go about it, I believe there is no 'right' way to structure your code.

Hope it helps

Comment: As you said, there is no wrong or right way to structure your code but in your case, what is the benefit you found in using Protocols instead of just using a ViewModel per view directly? Sorry if I'm not seeing the obvious.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I use protocols to only expose variables/functions of my viewmodels/services that my other classes needs to know about. I then instantiate my viewController by using the protocol type (see edited answer).

Comment: The benefit of refactoring to Service files is that your other viewmodels (for other views of the app) can benefit from the same functions from your service class

Comment: You can read more about the benefits of this kind of pattern here: https://medium.com/sudo-by-icalia-labs/ios-architecture-mvvm-c-services-6-6-c4d4184fdc01

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and code sample. In my case, I'm using SwiftUI but I get the concept. Thanks.

Comment: It works just as well for SwiftUI. Glad I could help.